# How can a local std::bernoulli_distribution create accurately distributed data?

Tags: c++

Here, I have a class `Generator` that has a random number engine and a method `genTrial()` that's supposed to return a `bool` representing the "success" or "failure" outcome of an independent trial. Using the std::bernoulli_distribution, I can assign the probability of getting a "success"; notice that this variable is local to `genTrial()`.

In the main code, I am generating 30,000 trials by repeatedly calling `genTrial()` with a success parameter of 25% in the loop. When the code runs, the distribution is correct.

My question is: Since the `std::bernoulli_distribution` variable is local, how does it know/remember the state of the distribution in order to still generate a correct data set? If a new variable is created/destroyed every iteration, there's no persistence of state and no way to know what's been done in the past, so how does it determine where to put the fed in number? Shouldn't it put the numbers in the same set?

**generator.h**

```cpp
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H




#include <random>


class Generator
{
    private:
        static std::mt19937 randEngine;

    public:
        bool genTrial(double success);
};







#endif
```

**generator.cpp**

```cpp
#include "generator.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>






std::mt19937 Generator::randEngine(0);





bool Generator::genTrial(double success)
{
    std::bernoulli_distribution distrib(success);
    return distrib(randEngine);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "generator.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int NUM_SAMPLES = 30000;
    const int NUM_OF_BINARY_VALUES = 2;
    const double SUCCESS_RATE = 0.25;

    Generator gen;
    int binaryRecord[NUM_OF_BINARY_VALUES] = {0};

    // "roll the dice"
    for(int x = 0; x < NUM_SAMPLES; x++)
    {
        bool thisRoll = gen.genTrial(SUCCESS_RATE);
        if(thisRoll == true) binaryRecord[1]++;
        else binaryRecord[0]++;
    }

    // draw the results
    for(int y = 0; y < NUM_OF_BINARY_VALUES; y++)
    {
        if(y == 0) std::cout << "[F]: ";
        else std::cout << "[T]: ";

        int numActualTallies = binaryRecord[y];
        int numDisplayedTallies = numActualTallies / 1000;
        for(int i = 0; i < numDisplayedTallies; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "*";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you think it needs to remember it's outcome?

Comment: like if you flip a coin. It would not remember anything but it's still p=0.5 to have head as  outcome.

Comment: `randEngine` has the state.

Comment: @appleapple Computers are deterministic machines. In order for a function to generate something different, it needs a state. Consider a function `bool throwCoin()`. Make it so it will give `true` or `false` 50/50 without a state...

Comment: @Mirko `std::mt19937` have pretty good entropy.

Comment: @appleapple Because it has a state

Comment: @Mirko so distribution don't need one.

Comment: a state less real-world random variable generator is also possible, it just (usually) not fast enough.

Comment: And it simulates entropy. You can have a stateless only if you use hardware, which is not portable and hence not part of the standard.

Comment: @Mirko so `std::bernoulli_distribution` can have no state. which is OP's question. I don't really get what you want to say, btw.

Comment: @Mirko just to make sure, you do agree that even if it give a sequence of 100 `true`, you cannot say it's wrong, because it's *random*.

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong way to think about it, but let's pretend there are 10 perfectly rational people standing in line (no human bias). The first person will say either "yes" or "no" knowing there is a 50% chance of "yes". The first says "yes" then leaves the line. The second says "yes", leaves. After 3 "yes"s, it's now the fourth's turn. If the fourth person knows there's a 50% chance of "yes" but doesn't know anything about what's already been said, then they could be completely fine with "yes" again even though 4 "yes"s is improbable.

Comment: Something has to know the record in order to say what's next or else your set wouldn't reflect what the odds are, right?

Comment: @delimiter no, 4 yes in sequence have p=0.0652. it's a valid outcome.

Comment: @delimiter this may help understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers (disclaimer: I didn't read the content)

Comment: @appleapple Saying "there's no state on `std::bernoulli_distribution`" is technically correct, but also incomplete and maybe useless: saying "there's no need for `std::bernoulli_distribution` to have a state because `std::mt19937` has a state" I think is a more complete answer and could give a hint to the OP about what he's thinking about (altough not what he textually asked for). Regards.

Comment: @Mirko I believe I say *std::bernoulli_distribution **can** have no state*. Why? according to our conversation, because `std::mt19937` has a state. (5 comment before that one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only state that [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) holds is the *p* distribution parameter that was used during construction. It doesn't need to remember previously output values to output the next value with the correct distribution. For example, it can generate a random `double` from the given random engine and return `true` if the value is less than *p*.

Your function constructs a new distribution each time it's called and passes the same *p* parameter value `SUCCESS_RATE`. You could rewrite your code to only construct `distrib` once. That might be more efficient than constructing it each time but the result would be the same, a stream of `bool` values with `true` appearing 25% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

`std::mt19937 Generator::randEngine(0);` this is your source of randomness.

Distributions extract randomness from engines and produce values.

Distributions are mostly stateless (after construction).  Their state is outsourced to the engine.